# How to create ruby text in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-text

I'm trying to add ruby text annotation so I can display furigana on top of kanji words in a Japanese app.  I believe CTRubyAnnotationCreateWithAttributes is the function to use to create ruby text but when I run this simple app it is only displaying the main text. Can someone point out what I am missing? Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let word = "食べ物"
    let ruby = "たべもの"
    
    var text = furigana(main: word, furigana: ruby)
    textView.attributedText = text
  }

  func furigana(main: String, furigana: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    
    var ruby = furigana
    var unmanage = Unmanaged.passRetained(ruby as CFString)
    defer { unmanage.release() }
    var text: [Unmanaged<CFString>?] = [unmanage, .none, .none, .none]
    
    let rubyAttribute: [AnyHashable: Any] = [
        kCTRubyAnnotationSizeFactorAttributeName: 0.5,
        kCTForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black
    ]
    
    let annotation = CTRubyAnnotationCreateWithAttributes(.auto, .auto, .before, ruby as CFString, rubyAttribute as CFDictionary)
    
    //let annotation = CTRubyAnnotationCreate(.center, .auto, 0.5, &text)
    
    let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(
      string: main,
      attributes: [kCTRubyAnnotationAttributeName as NSAttributedString.Key: annotation])
    
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.0
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 12
    
    attributed.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributed.length))
    attributed.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HiraMinProN-W3", size: 14.0)!, NSAttributedString.Key.verticalGlyphForm: false,],range: NSMakeRange(0, (attributed.length)))
    
    return attributed
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working with two changes:

1. Use a `UILabel` instead of a `UITextView`.
2. Remove the `verticalGlyphForm` attribute.

I'm not seeing any obvious documentation, but it appears that ruby text might not be supported on `UITextView`. As for `verticalGlyphForm`, [the documentation says it's not supported on iOS and if specified the behavior is undefined](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1528658-verticalglyphform).

[image: 食べ物 with furigana]